# Hittest for PathGeometry

Tags: wpf, shapes

I have a custom `Shape` with `PathGeometry` as `DefiningGeometry`.
The PathGeometry displays a text.

I notice that when one tries to select the Shape on the Canvas, you have to exactly on the text border of the Path.

I would like to be able to hit the rectangle around it.
How would you solve that, should I add a transparant Rectangle geometry?

---

Code for Krishna:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TextLabel}">
    <c:Label Left="{Binding Left}" Top="{Binding Top}" IsDragEnabled="True" DragDeltaCommand="{Binding DragCommand}" Text="{Binding Text}" ToolTip="{Binding Code}" Fill="Black" StrokeThickness="0" x:Name="Label"/>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Label" Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

But `c:Label` is just a custom shape with formatted text. The `Fill` is the Brush of the text. So the space between/around characters is not part of the shape. Is it possible to add a transparant rectangle so that this rectangle takes part in the hittest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works:
Top, Left are custom DP to give the shape an exact location on the Canvas (they replace Canvas.Top, Canvas.Left).

```
protected override HitTestResult HitTestCore(PointHitTestParameters hitTestParameters)
{
    var result = base.HitTestCore(hitTestParameters);
    if (result == null && hitTestParameters.HitPoint.X < (Left + geometry.Bounds.Width) && hitTestParameters.HitPoint.X > Left)
    {
        if (hitTestParameters.HitPoint.Y < (Top + geometry.Bounds.Height) && hitTestParameters.HitPoint.Y > Top)
        {
            result = new PointHitTestResult(this, hitTestParameters.HitPoint);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the background property of the container to be Transparant and then it will work.

For example if your path is inside a grid then Grid.Background="Transparant"

Sorry for these edits, Can you just try something? Put c:Label inside an empty grid and see what happens. Like

```
<Grid Background=White> 
<c:Label Left="{Binding Left}" ...x:Name="Label"/>
</Grid>
```

You might have to change the triggers and put them inside Grid.Style

Comment: The shape is in a listboxitem, sorry your suggestion does not work.

Comment: Can you post the item template please? Or can you check if mousedown (for your selection) is getting handled by some other control using snoop?

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. Have you got a style for c:Label? That must have a container surely? Can you just hardcode a color like white to the background (or fill) of that container please?

Comment: That might work in some cases. But I want control about the exact location of the grid on the canvas via a shape.